# Checking in_array value

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Image for explaining my question.]

The Image above is what I want to achieve, the only problem is am echoing subjects and topics where the topics go under the subjects, but I want to only echo say English and all topics under English will go under English. But what I have is every topic comes with its own Subjects. Thus from the Image Two English Language dropdowns.
Here is the code.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT note_id, class, subject, topic, content, author FROM notes WHERE class = 'JHS 2'";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row=$result->fetch()){
        if(!in_array('subject', $row['subject']){
?>
<li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><?php echo $row['subject']?><i class="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i></a>
<div class="collapsible-body">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a data-id="<?php echo $row['note_id']?>" href="<?php echo $row['note_id']?>" class="waves-effect" id="getUser"><?php echo $row['topic']?></a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<?php
        } else {
            echo ""
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Show your tables.

Comment: As in mysql tables?

Comment: Why not change your SQL statement to only return the rows you want instead of the if statement? IOW, add to your where clause ```subject <> 'subject'```.

Comment: Also, edit your question and show what your code currently produces. IOW, you show what you want, show what you are getting. It might also help to show the html output you are getting now, and the html code you want to get. Edit your question and put the html in as code, not an image.

Comment: what my code produces is in the picture uploaded.  Which is correct. But what I want to do is when only one subject should be echoed, not twice as seen in the picture.

Comment: Add an order by clause to your query so that the subjects are in order.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't show how you output the difference between topics and subjects.

Answer (score 0):

This should output the subjects and topics and allows for multiple subjects per topic. Also, the echo "" in the else is un-needed.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT note_id, class, subject, topic, content, author FROM notes WHERE class = 'JHS 2' ORDER BY subject, topic";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $lastSubject = '';
    while($row=$result->fetch()){
        if(!in_array('subject', $row['subject']) {
            if($lastSubject != $row['subject']) {
?>
<li><a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i><?php echo $row['subject']?><i class="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i></a>
<div class="collapsible-body">
<?php
            }
?>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a data-id="<?php echo $row['note_id']?>" href="<?php echo $row['note_id']?>" class="waves-effect" id="getUser"><?php echo $row['topic']?></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
            if($lastSubject != $row['subject']) {
?>
</div>
<?php
                $lastSubject = $row['subject'];
            }
?>
</li>
<?php
        }
    }

?>
```